# create values folder for specific android device samsung gt s5303

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have an application that works fine in almost devices but the only device that fail is samsung gt s5303, I want to add a different value folder just for that device and add to it my dim file , I have tried to add values-sw320dp , but I found that it make other devices read from the same values folder

so how can I solve this problem please

This is the full specs. of the device 
http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_y_plus_s5303-5357.php

Comment: From the specs, looks like the phone's screen density is mdpi (please confirm with `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`): try with **values-sw320dp-mdpi**

Comment: I have tried
values-sw320dp (Not Working on tablet)
values-sw320dp-mdpi (Not Working on tablet)
values-w240dp-h320dp-mdpi (Not Working on tablet)
values-w240px-h320px-mdpi (Not Compile Project)

Comment: I thought you were asking about GT-S5303 which appears to be a phone. Why are you expecting those values to be used on tablets?

Comment: The application supposed to run on different devices with different size, including Samsung Tablet GT- P3100

Comment: OK, but why are you expecting **values-sw320dp*** to be used on tablets?

Comment: I'm not expecting I have the real devices and when I'm testing on them and I have that strange behaviour